# Jumio netvrify error when using webview in iOS. Browser does not support camera

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios-camera

I have website that redirect user to do eKYC through Jumio. It was working fine on Desktop browser, Mobile Browser, Android App(webview).

However, when come to iOS app(wkwebview), my user keeps getting error as in cant complete the eKYC process. Once the user click on start eKYC process, it straight away return failed result. The error code from Jumio is "9822 (Browser does not support camera.)".

I have already enable camera usage in plist and enable camera permission in iOS for the APP. Not sure where went wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question with a [example] showing the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know webrtc is not available in webwiew (UIWebView or WKWebwiew). So you can't have camera access directly from the webview. You will need to open safari or bridge the webrtc call to a native implementation.